# Error in the return of values

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When running getTicket ()

```
Alert (JSON.stringify (responseJson));
```

Data is recovered properly
But in listTicket (), the other data is shown to me
My code is as follows

getTicket:

```
async getTicket ()
    {
      try {
        let response = await fetch(
          'url'
        ,{
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            uid: '1',
            type: '0',
          })
        });

        let responseJson = await response.json();
        alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson));
        return responseJson;
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
      }

    }
```

listTicket code:

```
listTicket()
   {

     let objectTicket = this.getTicket();


     alert(JSON.stringify(objectTicket));
   }
```

please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @JJJ thanks , I saw the link but did not notice, can you might correct code?

Comment: you don't need return response, just use setState() instead return responseJson;

Comment: @xadm When I use setState, the listTicket function is placed in the loop

Comment: it shouldn't when called from componentDidMount - it can when ABUSED, called from render and some other lifecycle methods

Comment: @xadm yes I used the listTicket on the render because I want to display some views dynamically. But when I delete this.setState in getTicket, the loop problem is resolved. What solution would you recommend to resolve the problem?

Comment: it shouldn't be called from render!! fetch (from cDM) receives data and saves in state (setState), updating state forces new render (with new data)

Comment: @xadm Where should I call listTicket? Before render (), i get an error, thanks

Comment: you don't need `listTicket` at all. call `this.getTicket()` from `componentDidMount`.    what kind of error??

Comment: @xadm I often need to call the function with different parameters. As far as I know, componentDidMount runs only once.

Comment: make this simple flow working - if there're other requirements then show more, non theoretical code

Comment: @xadm i used componentDidMount but i get null, i add new post , please help

Answer (score 1):

Just call `this.getTicket()` like this to get the promis returned from the async function:

```
this.getTicket()()
  .then(function(objectTicket) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(objectTicket));
  });
```

Comment: thanks, Is there a better solution? I used the {this.listTicket {}} in render () and I'm going to use some views in map by listTicket

Comment: Like @xadm said, just store your responseJson in the state - you know what I mean?

Comment: When I use setState, the listTicket function is placed in the loop